# vb .net application stopped working event name clr20r3

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2012, .net-framework-version

[image]I have an application that was originally written in VB6 and migrated to VB.Net. I compiled it in Visual Studio 2010 and it runs successfully on windows 7. However when I try to run it in windows 2012 server it generates the following error log:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: clientlaunchutility.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 4.7.5654.21332   
  Problem Signature 03: 558ba4d8   
  Problem Signature 04: ClientLaunchUtility
  Problem Signature 05: 4.7.5654.21332
  Problem Signature 06: 558ba4d8
  Problem Signature 07: b
  Problem Signature 08: ca
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
```

How can I get this working again?

Comment: Could you give us a little more than just an error log?

Comment: i have made app in vb6 and migrate to vb .net . I compiled it in visual studio 2010 and run on windows 7 it runs successfully but when i run it in windows 2012 server . it gives me error log like i mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the versions of .Net are the same on both the development workstation and the server? You may very well have compiled it for a version that is beyond what you have installed on the Windows 2012 server.
(or vice-versa)

Comment: On development work station the version of .Net framework is 2.0 and on server it includes 3.5 .net framework and also includes 2.0 and 3.0.